# How do I add prev and next buttons to my jQuery slider?

Tags: jquery, slider

I have created a basic jQuery slider following [a tutorial from TheHelpingDevelop](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yikHrIMsccw). I have changed the slider to be a flexible width and made the images fade instead of slide.

I would like to know how to incorporate previous and next buttons in the slider.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Slider</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    .slider{
        position: relative;
        width:80%;
        height:350px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 30px auto;
    }

    .slider img{
        width: 100%;
        height: inherit;
        display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body onload="slider()">
   <div class="slider">
       <img id="1" src="img/image1.png" border="0" alt="">
       <img id="2" src="img/image2.png" border="0" alt="">
       <img id="3" src="img/image3.png" border="0" alt="">
   </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function slider() {
        $('.slider #1').fadeIn();
        $('.slider #1').delay(5500).fadeOut();

        var sc = $('#.slider img').size();
        var count = 2;
        var slider = $('.slider')

        setInterval(function (){
            $('.slider #'+count).fadeIn(500);
            $('.slider #'+count).delay(5500).fadeOut();

                if(count == sc){
                    count = 1;
                }else{
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            },6500);

        }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would also like to know how to remove the gap between the fading image so that I do not see the background during transition. This would make the slider more fluent.

See [demo in JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rKzxk/16/).

Comment: try to add a jsfiddle. I am not able to create a slider with your code

Comment: there is one typo, it should be: `var sc = $('.slider img').size();`

Comment: http://wowslider.com/jquery-slideshow-huge-demo.html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rKzxk/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified the code to adjust image opacity, positioned all images absolutely to common place, so now  the transitions between two images can be animated. Added also simple next and previous controls.

javascript:

```js
function slider() {

    function animate_slider(){
        $('.slider #'+shown).animate({
            opacity:0 // fade out
        },1000);
        $('.slider #'+next_slide).animate({
            opacity:1.0 // fade in
        },1000);
        shown = next_slide;
    }

    function choose_next() {
        next_slide = (shown == sc)? 1:shown+1;
        animate_slider();
    }

    $('.slider #1').css({opacity:1}); //show 1st image
    var shown = 1;
    var next_slide;
    var sc = $('.slider img').length; // total images
    var iv = setInterval(choose_next,3500);
    $('.slider_nav').hover(function(){
        clearInterval(iv); // stop animation
    }, function() {
        iv = setInterval(choose_next,3500); // resume animation
    });
    $('.slider_nav span').click(function(e){
        var n = e.target.getAttribute('name');
        if (n=='prev') {
            next_slide = (shown == 1)? sc:shown-1;
        } else if(n=='next') {
            next_slide = (shown == sc)? 1:shown+1;
        } else {
            return;
        }
        animate_slider();
    });
}

window.onload = slider;
```

additional HTML:

```html
<div class="slider_nav">
    <span name="prev"> previous </span> /
    <span name="next"> next image </span>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/pjTU2/)

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. fantastic!

Comment: would it be possible to use images for the next and prev buttons? i seem to be having trouble with it

Comment: Thank you, here is [the updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/pjTU2/14/). Greetings

Answer (score 0):

i always use pure js , not jQuery ; but i explain to you , what you need to do ( hope this helps )

as yourself do that , you should put a variable in your code for image names or their id . now you should create a code to change the number of id , when user click on an element ! what is that element ? exactly the next or prev button !
like this :

```
nextButton.onclick=function(){

$('.slider #'+count).fadeOut();
count=count+1
$('.slider #'+count).fadeIn(slow);

}
```

it is a simple example ; you can do it at your own way . good luck ...

Answer (score 0):

See this 
http://jsfiddle.net/rKzxk/19/

```
<body onload="slider()">
    <div class="slider">
        <img id="1" src="http://top-frog.com/stuff/slider/images/slider-test-image-1.gif" border="0" alt="">
        <img id="2" src="http://top-frog.com/stuff/slider/images/slider-test-image-2.gif" border="0" alt="">
        <img id="3" src="http://top-frog.com/stuff/slider/images/slider-test-image-3.gif" border="0" alt="">
    </div>
    <input type=button id="prev" value="Prev">
    <input type=button id="next" value="Next">
</body>
```

Script

```
 function slider() {
     $('#1').fadeIn();
     $('#1').delay(5500).fadeOut();

     var sc = $('.slider img').size();
     var count = 2;
     var slider = $('.slider')


     myTimer = setInterval(slide, 6500);

     function slide() {
         slideActual();
         if (count == sc) {
             count = 1;
         } else {
             count = count + 1;
         }
     }

     function slideActual() {
         $('#' + count).fadeIn(100);
         $('#' + count).delay(5500).fadeOut(100);

     }
     $("#next").click(function () {

         clearInterval(myTimer);
         if(count==1){
            $('#' + sc).fadeOut(100);
         }else{
                $('#' + count-1).fadeOut(100);
         }
         slideActual();
         if (count == sc) {
             count = 1;
         } else {
             count = count + 1;
         }
         myTimer = setInterval(slide, 6500);
     });
     $("#prev").click(function () {
           if(count==1){
            $('#' + sc).fadeOut(100);
         }else{
                $('#' + count-1).fadeOut(100);
         }

         if (count == 1) {
             count = sc-1;
         } else if (count == 2) {
             count = sc;
         } else {
             count = count - 2;
         }
         clearInterval(myTimer);

         slideActual();
         if (count == sc) {
             count = 1;
         } else {
             count = count + 1;
         }
         myTimer = setInterval(slide, 6500);
     });
 }
```

css

```
.slider {
    position: relative;
    width:80%;
    height:350px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
.slider img {
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: @aztekgold On Which browser you are trying.. see the  jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rKzxk/19/... its working right on chrome..

Comment: im using chrome and when on image 2 clicking next returns me to image 1

Comment: @aztekgold works well in mine. the code should give you basic idea what you need to do. you can play/manipulate with calculation.